# Returning Sql Results based on Ranking

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I return  a list the top three athletes for a given Country and Sport Using the 6 tables below based on the number of medals the athletes win in that Sport ?

```
ATHLETES

+------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| idATHLETES | ATHLETENAME     | TEAMS_idTEAMS | TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| JG         | JUSTIN GATLIN   | USA-TF-MEN    | USA                     |
| MS         | MARIA SHARAPOVA | RUS-WTA       | RUS                     |
| SW         | SERENA WILLIAMS | USA-WTA       | USA                     |
| UB         | USAIN BOLT      | JAM-TF-MEN    | JAM                     |
| VW         | VENUS WILLIAMS  | USA-WTA       | USA                     |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+

EVENTS

+------------+---------------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------+
| idEVENTS   | EVENTNAME     | ATHLETES_idATHLETES | ATHLETES_TEAMS_idTEAMS | ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY | VARIOUS_SPORTS_SPORTS_ID |
+------------+---------------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------+
| ATH        | ATHLETICS     | JG                  | USA-TF-MEN             | USA                              | TRACK-AND-FIELD          |
| ATH        | ATHLETICS     | UB                  | JAM-TF-MEN             | JAM                              | TRACK-AND-FIELD          |
| TEN        | TENNIS        | MS                  | RUS-WTA                | RUS                              | WOMENS_TENNIS            |
| TEN        | TENNIS        | VW                  | USA-WTA                | USA                              | WOMENS_TENNIS            |
| TEN-DOUBLE | TENNIS DOUBLE | SW                  | USA-WTA                | USA                              | WOMENS_TENNIS            |
| TEN-DOUBLE | TENNIS DOUBLE | VW                  | USA-WTA                | USA                              | WOMENS_TENNIS            |
+------------+---------------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------+

RESULTS

+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------
+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| idRESULTS | STATUS      | MEDALS | EVENTS_idEVENTS | EVENTS_ATHLETES_idATHLETES | EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_idTEAMS | EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY | EVENTS_VARIOUS_SPORTS_SPORTS_ID |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| results1  | DID-NOT-WIN | SILVER | TEN             | MS                         | RUS-WTA                       | RUS                                     | WOMENS_TENNIS                   |
| results1  | WON         | GOLD   | TEN             | VW                         | USA-WTA                       | USA                                     | WOMENS_TENNIS                   |
| results2  | DID-NOT-WIN | BRONZE | ATH             | JG                         | USA-TF-MEN                    | USA                                     | TRACK-AND-FIELD                 |
| results2  | WON         | GOLD   | ATH             | UB                         | JAM-TF-MEN                    | JAM                                     | TRACK-AND-FIELD                 |
| results3  | WON         | GOLD   | TEN-DOUBLE      | SW                         | USA-WTA                       | USA                                     | WOMENS_TENNIS                   |
| results3  | WON         | GOLD   | TEN-DOUBLE      | VW                         | USA-WTA                       | USA                                     | WOMENS_TENNIS                   |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------------+

VARIOUS_SPORTS

+-----------------+----------------------+
| SPORTS_ID       | SPORTS_NAME          |
+-----------------+----------------------+
| TRACK-AND-FIELD | MENS TRACK AND FIELD |
| WOMENS_TENNIS   | WOMENS TENNIS        |
+-----------------+----------------------+

THE_COUNTRY

+-----------+-------------+
| idCOUNTRY | COUNTRYNAME |
+-----------+-------------+
| JAM       | JAMAICA     |
| RUS       | RUSSIA      |
| USA       | USA         |
+-----------+-------------+

THE_TEAMS

+------------+----------------------------------+-------------------+
| idTEAMS    | TEAMNAME                         | COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY |
+------------+----------------------------------+-------------------+
| JAM-TF-MEN | jamaican track and field men     | JAM               |
| RUS-WTA    | russian women tennis association | RUS               |
| USA-TF-MEN | usa track and field men          | USA               |
| USA-WTA    | usa womens tennis association    | USA               |
+------------+----------------------------------+-------------------+
```

I have this code so far but this does not return the required output ?

```
SELECT idATHLETES, ATHLETENAME, TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY, COUNTRYNAME FROM
athletes
JOIN EVENTS ON idATHLETES = idEVENTS
JOIN teams ON TEAMS_idTEAMS =idTEAMS
JOIN country ON COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY = idCOUNTRY
JOIN RESULTS ON ATHLETES_idATHLETES = EVENTS_ATHLETES_idATHLETES

WHERE EVENTS_VARIOUS_SPORTS_SPORTS_ID = 'WOMENS_TENNIS' AND EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY ='USA' ;
```

Comment: It's going to need a GROUP BY on athlete, country, and sport, and a COUNT on medals then you can use ORDER BY and MySQL's LIMIT to get just the top 3.

Comment: To get top 3, you should add sort. But how can you sort on a "MEDALS" which is a string? It's better to make that field as integer.

Comment: How about adding another table for Medals & points - Gold - 3, Silver - 2, Bronze - 1, None - 0. Add a join for that & SUM(points), grouping by idAthletes, ordering by the sum of points descending limit 3

Comment: so basically like one more table with values of each medal assigned to it?

Comment: Or you could do so in the query as I indicated on my answer.

Comment: I will pay you to change the schema column names. Still trying to get over last nights question :p

Comment: haha how much will you pay :). Great answer yesterday btw ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider grouping by athlete and counting the medals.

```
SELECT idATHLETES, ATHLETENAME, TEAMNAME, COUNTRYNAME
      , MEDALS = SUM(CASE WHEN MEDALS IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
      , SCORE = SUM(CASE MEDALS WHEN 'Gold' THEN 3
                WHEN 'Silver' THEN 2
                WHEN 'Bronze' THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END)
      , GOLD = SUM(CASE MEDALS WHEN 'Gold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      , SILVER = SUM(CASE MEDALS WHEN 'Silver' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      , BRONZE = SUM(CASE MEDALS WHEN 'Bronze' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM ATHLETES
JOIN TEAMS ON TEAMS_idTEAMS = idTEAMS
JOIN COUNTRY ON COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY = idCOUNTRY
JOIN RESULTS ON ATHLETES_idATHLETES = EVENTS_ATHLETES_idATHLETES
WHERE EVENTS_VARIOUS_SPORTS_SPORTS_ID = 'WOMENS_TENNIS'
AND EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY ='USA'
GROUP BY idATHLETES, ATHLETENAME, TEAMNAME, COUNTRYNAME
ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN MEDALS IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

If you need to assign different point to each medal you could do so by changing the `ORDER BY`clause to:

```
ORDER BY SUM(CASE MEDALS WHEN 'Gold' THEN 3
                WHEN 'Silver' THEN 2
                WHEN 'Bronze' THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END)
```

Alternatively you could create a table to hold the values.

Comment: Great answer this works!! Just one question if In  want to show the sum of the total medals won for each athlete from the sum besides each one, from this code, how can I do this ?

Comment: I added some columns to the query. I hope you find the one you were looking.

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot.